# How can I find the MinOccurs/MaxOccurs values using an instance of XmlSchema?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset, xsd

I am using `DataSet.ReadXmlSchema()` to construct a dataset, and `DataSet.ReadXml()` to load the data.

I am then binding to the dataset to edit the data.  I want to control inserting and deleting of rows in the tables in the dataset, based on the minOccurs and maxOccurs properties defined in my schema.

I have tried loading the schema below into an instance of `XmlSchema`, e.g. MySchema.  Given that minOccurs and maxOccurs default to 1, unless otherwise specified, the `LastName` and `FirstName` nodes should occur exactly once.  `Contacts` can occur 0 or 1 times, and `ContactName` can occur 0 to 10 times.

Once the `XmlSchema` instance is created, how can I reference the minOccurs and maxOccurs properties for the nodes?

I have found that the `XmlSchemaParticle` class contains MinOccurs and MaxOccurs properties, but I haven't been able to figure out how to navigate through the `XmlSchema` instance to find them.

I've tried looking at `MySchema.Items`, but that doesn't seem to contain the information.

Is this even the "best" approach?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Person.xsd" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <!--Required Nodes-->
        <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
        <!-- Optional Nodes-->
        <xs:element name="Contacts" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ContactName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Does anyone know how I can find the MinOccurs/MaxOccurs values from an instance of XmlSchema?  I have read the documentation at MSDN, and also tried navigating the class through the Visual Studio debugger, but I can not find the correct properties for these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the `DataSet` will respect minOccurs/maxOccurs.

In fact, `DataSet` does not map one-to-one to XML Schema. The `DataSet` class maps to a relational database model. Anything in XML Schema that doesn't map to that model will be ignored or transformed by `DataSet`.

An example was a case where I had elements of the same complex type as child elements of two different parents. I was able to read that schema into the `DataSet`, but `DataSet` in effect created a copy of my shared complex type, in order to match the Relational model. The XML schema I wrote back out did not match the schema I read in.

You should try writing out the schema using `WriteXmlSchema` and compare it to the schema you read in.

Comment: I don't expect the `DataSet` to support the minOccurs/maxOccurs directly.  I will do that in code by enabling/disabling the insert and delete buttons on my navigator.  I just need to find the minOccurs/maxOccurs values in the `XmlSchema'.  I appologize for being vague on that point.

Comment: Did you find [XmlSchemaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.aspx)?

Comment: _Finally_ looped back around to this project and managed to dig out the information that I needed.  The trick is to cast the `XmlSchemaElement` instance as an `XmlParticle`!  Accepted this answer based on the comment above, more than for the answer itself.